# Result from Jinja2 template returned as string in Ansible

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I try to set a variable on ansible using the jinja2 templates. In my playbook I have this:

```
- set_fact:
    restart: |
      {% for host in groups['primary'] %}
      {%   if hostvars[host].arbiter_host == inventory_hostname_short %}
      {{     restart | combine(hostvars[host].restart | dict2items | selectattr('key', 'regex', 'mongod_\d+$') | list | items2dict) }}
      {%   endif %}
      {% endfor %}

- debug:
    var: restart
```

The result is this one

```
ok: [my_host] => {
    "restart": "{u'mongod_01': True}\n{u'mongod_02': True}\n"
}
```

Which is almost fine, but the data is given as a single string. I need the get an dict as this:

```
ok: [my_host] => {
    "restart": {
        "mongod_01": true,
        "mongod_02": true,
    }
}
```

I tried almost everything, but noting succeeded. How to transform from string to dict object?

btw, it work fine when the dict object holds only one item but it fails with two or more.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found a solution:

```
set_fact:
  restart: |
    {% set services = {} %}
    {% for host in groups['primary'] %}
    {%   if hostvars[host].arbiter_host == inventory_hostname_short %}
    {%     set _ = services.update(hostvars[host].restart | dict2items | selectattr('key', 'regex', 'mongod_\d+$') | list | items2dict) %}
    {%   endif %}
    {% endfor %}
    {{ restart | combine(services) }}
```

Gives the desired result.